# How can I use Parsing to separate Int and characters from a string (java)

Tags: java, parsing, rpn

I am trying to create an RPN calculator.  I want the user to keep pushing numbers until they type a character but I don’t know how to do this.  Someone mentioned making the input into a string and then parsing it so I can separate it into int and char. Can I see an example of how this works.  It doesn't necessarily need to be for an RPN calculator.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want people to help you, it might be useful to provide some code attempts and what you already did to solve your problem.

Comment: as @MichaelLihs said, you should really show that you have attempted to do something.  Most people will not try to solve the whole problem for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example Java program:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Stack;

class Test {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    int data = inputStreamReader.read();
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    while (data != -1) {
      char c = (char)data;
      if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        stack.push(c);
      } else {
        // do whatever you want.
      }
      data = inputStreamReader.read();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the stack if the input character ch

`if(ch >='0' || ch <='9')
 stack.push(ch);
else
 //check for other characters`